# Is there any recommendation in Dart best practices how declare methods that operate with source and destination parameters?

Tags: coding-style, dart, parameter-passing

Is there any recommendation in Dart best practices how to declare methods that operate with source and destination parameters?

Which options preferred in Dart or this do not has much importance?

```dart
copy(dest, source);
```

```dart
copy(source, dest);
```

```dart
add(dest, source);
```

```dart
add(source, dest);
```

P.S.

I am interested only to know "Is there any official recommendation (best practice) or not?"

Comment: If you think it's likely to be confusing, use named parameters.

Comment: @AlanKnight Once Dart developers bring to mind the usage in combination of optional and named parameters then I will gladly take your advice. (https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6496 "Positional and optional parameter syntax is unwarranted")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen such a recommendation.

In the Dart API there's [`Converter<S,T>`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_convert/Converter.html) that takes Source before Target as parameter types.

I whould say it depends on the method. For `copy` I personally prefer *source* before *destination*.

Comment: This question was asked because in C/C++ libraries the `destination` always comes before `source`. Eg. `char *strcpy (char *dst, const char *src);`

Comment: For `copy` ***source*** before ***destination*** makes sense. For `copy` you may make ***destination*** an optional parameter where a new destination is created when not provided.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer To be more precise, I can say that this question refers to `copyTo` or `addTo` but not to `createCopy` as you think. Also `moveTo` and similar other.

Comment: For `copyTo` I would have put `destination` before `source`. That why I said : _I whould say it depends on the method_.

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin Thanks. Searching  `CopyTo` show that the `CopyTo` often used as instance method and means `read from the current and writes to another`. The `current` (this instance) in this case source. This is another story about how to call similar methods.

Answer (score 3):

There is no official recommendation.
The only source for that would be the Dart Style Guide, and it doesn't say anything about this subject.

The style chosen for the platform libraries is indeed "source before target". We find it more readable than the opposite, reading it as "copy from source to target"

In many cases the question is moot in an object oriented system, because it will be a method on either the source object or the target object, or even on both.

Comment: I think that the style guide is not a quite well place for recommendations about how to design good API. Also I think recommendation about how to design some aspects in Dart environment could be very useful. This recommendations can be based even on some traditions but not only on reasonable explanation. I think that at least Dart SDK must follow some recommendation and it would be useful that this rules would be publicly available. Intuitive way is not always the wisest. And, of course, it is not about Dart Style Guide but about the other useful guides.